# how can I remove token CRM:XXXX000 from email subject line in CRM2016

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Can anyone help to remove the token like CRM:XXXX000 from subject line of email generated through plugin code ?

CRM 2011 had some settings to remove this but in CRM 2016 I am not getting that  setting.

Am  I missing something or CRM2016 does not allow it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the tracking token which alows CRM to (as the name implies) keep track of the emails.

To remove the tracking token go to Settings > Administration > System settings > Tab Email and uncheck "Use Tracking Token"

Comment: Yes, I got that in today's morning when I was doing random search.

Thank you very much Alex for response.